# 冰雪聪明... only for girls?

Tags: mandarin, usage, idioms

Is the expression 冰雪聪明 (bīng xuě cōng míng) really only used for girls? The literal translation is "snow smart" and I understand it means something along the lines of "extremely smart" but the times I've tried using it for boys/men I'm told it's only for girls.

Comment: As it is used overwhelmingly for girls, I feel it sounds like a gay if use it to describe a man.

Comment: You can use tone numbers to indicate tones if you are not sure how to type letters with accent marks.

Comment: @deutschZuid this idiom should pronounce [bīng xuě cōng míng](http://www.zdic.net/c/0/10/26912.htm). Not `cōng ming`.

Comment: 冰 and 雪 implies purity and innocence, that's why 冰雪聪明 is mainly used to describe smart young girls.

Comment: @Stan Interesting. I have never heard anyone pronounce it like that.

Comment: @deutschZuid ... maybe I should have expressed more clearly. Yes, `聪明` **alone** can be pronounced as `cōng ming`, and it is quite often heard; however it's not a must, the [National Putonghua Proficiency Test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PSC#Other) doesn't put it in the ["must neutral tone" list](http://www.beijingputonghua.com/psc/qingsheng/qingsheng.htm), and the 现代汉语词典 fifth edition also marks it as `cōng míng` (well it is a constant argued issue). In `冰雪聪明`, the `cōng ming` sound is not natural, so at least I don't suggest pronouncing it like that.

Comment: I'd would rather suggest not to realize most neutral tones, except for words like 的 得 地(adverb marker) 妈妈 爸爸. Southern speakers don't really speak with neutral tones and Taiwanese mandarin also has much fewer words with neutral tones...

Comment: Like the word "cute", (可爱), which in the not too distant past was used quite exclusively for girls, particularly young girls. But in our present "mixed-up" World, anything goes. Be that as it may, I still think that expressions like 漂亮, 美丽 are for girls only.

Answer (score 5):

冰雪聪明 always describes that someone is very clever and smart. It comes from `唐·杜甫《送樊二十三侍御赴汉中判官》诗：“坐知七曜历，手画三军势。冰雪净聪明，雷霆走精锐。”`. But `冰雪聪明` is **not only for girl**.

`冰雪聪明` can be used to describe the child too----冰雪聪明的孩子, but be careful when you use it to describe adult, especially male adult.

Other examples in ancient articles:

> 以冰雪聪明的文章，写雷霆精锐的思想，这种议论，就容易动人听闻了。（清·曾朴《孽海花》第十回）
>
> 姬冰雪聪明，靡不淹悟，类多韜匿不言。(清·陈孟楷 《湘烟小录·香畹楼忆语》)

Source：

[為何叫冰雪聰明](http://blog.udn.com/glwang/3277222)

Answer (score 3):

I would say, in most cases it is used to describe young girls. In some other cases, if people want to make their comments/conversation to take a flavor of humor, they can be used to describe boys/men.

才貌双全 is relatively more neutral.

Answer (score 2):

According to baidu (http://baike.baidu.com/view/117274.htm), it is usually used to describe women, but can occasionally be used to describe men as well.  "这个词通常用来形容年轻女子。 ... 有时也可用于才貌双全的男性。"

Answer (score -1):

Yes. This word is ususally for girls.

Comment: Can you explain more?